# What does "grab" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Toby Keith said of Obama in 2009:

> I'm giving our commander in chief a chance before I **start grabbing**. So far, I'm cool with it."

It appears on [Toby Keith's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toby_Keith) and originally apparently came from a [Politico article](https://www.politico.com/story/2009/04/video-toby-keith-cool-with-obama-021557).

What does the verb "grab" mean in this context? It does sound like to grasp.

**Edit:**

Courtesy of godel9, the original interview is available in [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_YJgbum4WU&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I have no idea what **grabbing** would mean in that context. It is possible he said **griping** and was misheard.

Comment: What is the source?  Are you sure it's "grabbing" and not something that sounds similar, like "griping" or "crabbing", which mean "to complain"?  Toby Keith does have an accent.

Comment: It's certainly not an *established* idiomatic usage - I don't recall ever hearing it, and it's not easy to find relevant references online. My guess is it might be a metaphoric extension from ***grab = snatch, bind, stick** [as in car brakes, leading to jerky deceleration].* The context pretty strongly implies that ***to grab*** means ***to pass [negative / critical] judgement*** here. Unless, as suggested, it's some kind of mistranscription. But either way, it's probably not worth "learning" the "meaning".

Comment: Perhaps it's just an accidentally interpolated **R**. I.e. - *before I start **gabbing** / running off at the mouth / wittering on [about Obama].*

Comment: Source clarified

Comment: What do you mean "source clarified"? The term was mistyped or misheard by some machine transcription program, probably. It happens all the time. Grabbing makes no sense here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [video](https://youtu.be/m_YJgbum4WU), I believe he’s saying “crabbing” to mean:

> **crab**, intransitive verb: carp, grouse [(M-W, def. 5)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crab)
>
> **grouse**, intransitive verb: complain, grumble [(M-W, def. 2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grouse)

As others have suspected, it appears to have been transcribed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to hear the audio of the original interview .. but since the source of the statement is a Politico article, we have to assume that the writer faithfully transcribed what Toby Keith actually said.

In which case your guess is probably as good as mine, but if forced to paraphrase Keith's statement, I would assume "grabbing" is an ellipsis for "grasping at things to complain about".  It's the only thing that fits the context.